# Squid + ClamAV + i-cap: Scanning proxy for uploaded files?

Tags: squid, clamav

I'm trying to configure a virus scanning proxy server specifically to scan files being uploaded.  Scanning flies being downloaded seems to be the common use case, and seems to be well documented.

Not being a squid or i-cap expert, I'm using information from these guides:

http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_11.04&p=clamav
http://squidclamav.darold.net/installv6.html

**The A/V proxy is working as expected for file downloads, but is not working for file uploads.**  What am I missing?

Here is the i-cap configuration from squid.conf:

```
icap_enable on
icap_send_client_ip on
icap_send_client_username on
icap_client_username_encode off
icap_client_username_header X-Authenticated-User
icap_preview_enable on
icap_preview_size 1024
icap_service service_req reqmod_precache bypass=1 icap://127.0.0.1:1344/squidclamav
adaptation_access service_req allow all
icap_service service_resp respmod_precache bypass=1 icap://127.0.0.1:1344/squidclamav
adaptation_access service_resp allow all
```

Let me know if there is any other information I can provide to help get to the bottom of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a limitation in c-icap. This [reference](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=21172209) is a bit old, but the main developer of c-icap says:

> It has to do with the way the data coded in POST requests.
>   When the POST request will contain multipart form data will not work well.

This means that uploads aren't well supported on c-icap. It seems the only option you have is to replace c-icap with another ICAP server but, from my research, it seems that all the others are rather old or abandoned.

Comment: So using two squids on the same machine and make an upload a download on one of them may work?

Comment: it is not the answer I was looking for but your research deserves bounty. thank you